# Google Play Publishing App Screenshot Error

Tags: google-play, google-play-services, google-play-console

My app publish rejected due to this error but I can not find the source probably I am looking in wrong section.I am not native can anyone explain what this error does and how I fix it ?
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTGf8.png)
EDİT:
Sorry I didnt realize there is attachment , I belive I have to add contact info(my gmail) to main screen I probably add with info button or something , gladly accepting ideas.
[Attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Klxj.png)

Comment: In the screenshot it says there is an attached screenshot with the error, can you add it here?

Comment: I added now.thanks for the help.

Comment: I didn't see anything wrong in the screenshot. Please try Martin Pellicer's answer below...

Answer (score 1):

look at the final of the page (the page where you took the screenshot) there is an attached button where google play shows you the exact problem.
Also go to console -> all my apps -> developer account and check that you fill all the information